# sscanf problems when loading a string from it

Tags: c++, string, winapi, opengl, std

So, I was making a model loader for my project in OpenGL.
I am loading Wavefront OBJ Model files.
It loads nicely, but the big problem is when loading the MTL file.

I use sscanf to read data from the file.
MTL materials tell on the file the name of the image.

Something like: `map_Kd image.bmp`

The problem comes when I am reading the image name from the file.

I use the LoadImage() function to get the pixel data from bitmap files.
It throws an Unhandled Exception message () when I tell it to load the give file name.
Yes, I have the image in the project folder and all of it's subfolders in case the problem was that.

This is the message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x57e1d51c (msvcr100d.dll) in OBJ MODEL LOADER.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x622e656d.
```

This is the function I use to load the image:

```
GLuint load_texture(char* path)
{
    GLuint tex;
    HBITMAP bm = 0;
    bm = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    BITMAP b;
    GetObject(bm, sizeof(b), &b);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, b.bmWidth, b.bmHeight, 0, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, b.bmBits);

return tex;
}
```

And this is the function where it gets the image name(and so...):

```
void load_material(char* mtlpath, int loc, MODEL &m)
{
    std::ifstream a(mtlpath);
    std::vector<std::string*> file;
    char buff[255];
    if(!a.is_open())
    {
        MessageBox(g_hwnd, "Error when loading a specific material in the MTL file", "MTL(II) ERROR", 0);
    }

    while(!a.eof())
    {
        a.getline(buff, 255);
        file.push_back(new std::string(buff));
    }

    char* name;
    char* image;
    GLuint ii;

    sscanf(file[loc]->c_str(), "newmtl %c*",&name);
    for(int i = loc; i < file.size(); i++)
    {
        if((file[i]->c_str()[0] == 'm'))// && (file[i]->c_str()[1] == 'a') && (file[i]->c_str()[2] == 'p') && (file[i]->c_str()[3] == '_') && (file[i]->c_str()[4] == 'K') && (file[i]->c_str()[5] == 'd'))
        {
            sscanf(file[i]->c_str(), "map_Kd %s", &image);
            SetWindowText(g_hwnd, image);
            break;
        }
    }
    std::ofstream s("aa.txt");
    s << image;
    s.close();
    ii = 0;
    m.m.push_back(new material(name, image, ii));
    a.close();
}
```

I already tried to change %s(sscanf call) to %*c, %c, %*c, %c[^] and multiple others.

I also have to mention that I tried to directly put my image name in the "image" variable without retrieving it from the file, and it works perfectly like that.

What can I do to successfully retrieve the image name from the string?

By the way, I don't want to use any other stuff(MCI, SDL);

Comment: I am pretty sure the last thing you want is a `%c` format string. That will read a single character (and this single character includes whitespace that other format types ignore). `%s` at least strips out leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

In short: replace `std::vector<std::string*>` with `std::vector<std::string>` and `scanf` with `std::stringstream`.

Comment: how can stringstream do the job for me? Explain better, please

Comment: Try googling for std::stringstream, you'll find plenty of examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`%c` reads a single character, but you are trying to read a string instead, so you need to use `%s`.

When using `%s` with `sscanf()`, the destination buffer must be pre-allocated beforehand, but you are not doing that.  You are passing uninitialized `char*` pointers to `sscanf()`, so it tries to write string data to random memory, causing crashes.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void load_material(char* mtlpath, int loc, MODEL &m)
{
    std::ifstream a(mtlpath);
    std::vector<std::string> file;
    char buff[256];

    if (!a.is_open())
    {
        MessageBox(g_hwnd, "Error when loading a specific material in the MTL file", "MTL(II) ERROR", 0);
    }

    while (a.getline(buff, 255))
    {
        buff[a.gcount()] = '\0';
        file.push_back(buff);
    }
    a.close();

    char name[256] = {0};
    char image[256] = {0};
    GLuint ii;

    sscanf(file[loc].c_str(), "newmtl %255s", name);
    for(int i = loc; i < file.size(); i++)
    {
        if (sscanf(file[i].c_str(), "map_Kd %255s", image) == 1)
        {
            SetWindowText(g_hwnd, image);
            break;
        }
    }

    std::ofstream s("aa.txt");
    s << image;
    s.close();
    ii = 0;
    m.m.push_back(new material(name, image, ii));
}
```

Or, get rid of `sscanf()`, you do not really need it in this situation:

```
void load_material(char* mtlpath, int loc, MODEL &m)
{
    std::ifstream a(mtlpath);
    std::vector<std::string> file;
    std::string buff;

    if (!a.is_open())
    {
        MessageBox(g_hwnd, "Error when loading a specific material in the MTL file", "MTL(II) ERROR", 0);
    }

    while (std::getline(a, buff))
        file.push_back(buff);
    a.close();

    std::string name;
    std::string image;
    GLuint ii;

    if (file[loc].compare(0, 7, "newmtl ", 7) == 0)
        name = file[loc].substr(7);

    for(int i = loc; i < file.size(); i++)
    {
        if (file[i].compare(0, 7, "map_Kd ", 7) == 0)
        {
            image = file[i].substr(7);
            SetWindowText(g_hwnd, image.c_str());
            break;
        }
    }

    std::ofstream s("aa.txt");
    s << image;
    s.close();
    ii = 0;
    m.m.push_back(new material(name.c_str(), image.c_str(), ii));
}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work very well because of incompatibility issues with the loader structs. Using char image[255] makes it almost impossible to work with. It seams that sscanf is not returning anything. image is still empty;

Comment: No need to worry. I found the perfect solution. It is .substr and .find_last_of. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @HelderArmando: hard to say since you did not show any of the data you are actually parsing.